# Hyperlinks in Xaml to navigate from one page to another

Tags: c#, xaml, windows

How can I create Hyperlinks in Xaml to navigate from one page to another page? I don't know actually how to use the hyperlink tags.

Comment: What did you tried? What failed? Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RequestNavigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.requestnavigate.aspx) event to add a [HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.aspx) class

Xaml:

```
<TextBlock>           
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
        Click here
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for navigating to another page :

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="120,0,120,60">
   <HyperlinkButton Content="Click to go to page 2" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And handle it like :

```
 private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage2));
 }
```

And to move to external page : As mentioned by @Brainy